# How to get/decrypt token in next 13 app directory?

Tags: cookies, next.js

How do I access this cookie inside of a server component so that each user has their own userId which is set by the middelware.ts?

I tried to read the next docs but I can't seem to figure it out. Not sure if I'm accessing it properly as the "else" statement is never triggered. Appears in console on refresh: set new userId cookie { name: 'userId', value: '12345' }

No new cookies appear in Browser Dev tools > Application > Cookies

middleware.ts

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  if (req.nextUrl.pathname === "/") {

    if (!req.cookies.has("userId")) {
      req.cookies.set("userId", "12345")
      const userId = req.cookies.get("userId")
      console.log("set new userId cookie", userId)
    } else {
      const userId = req.cookies.get("userId")
      console.log("Existing userId:", userId)
    }
  }
  return NextResponse.next()
}

export const config = {
  matcher: "/"
}
```

code in server component:

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers"
...
      const cookiesStore = cookies()
      const userId = cookiesStore.get("userId");
      console.log(userId)
...
```

the above logs "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the value field accessor in order to get the cookie value.
With the App dir and NextJS v13.4 version
Like this example:

```
const cookieStore = cookies();
const userIdCookie = cookieStore.get('userId');

// ... Check if userIdCookie is defined, add some checks

const val: string = userIdCookie.value;
```

And that's it :)